# Why does the countdown stop when I set the time zone?

Tags: javascript

I have used a countdown to get the difference between two times. When I use the special time the timer stops despite time gets the difference when refreshing the browser I find it already counts but it doesn't show counting seconds.

```
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>

    // given the city's UTC offset
function calcTime(city, offset) {

// create Date object for current location
d = new Date();

// convert to msec
// add local time zone offset 
// get UTC time in msec
utc = d.getTime() + (d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);

// create new Date object for different city
// using supplied offset
nd = new Date(utc + (3600000*offset));

// return time as a string
return nd;

}

  var xx = calcTime('country1', '+3');
  var x1 = calcTime('country2', '-1');
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date(xx).getTime();
var now = new Date(x1).getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

    // Get todays date and time      //1527885631789
    //var now2 = new Date().getTime();  //1527871237519

    // Find the distance between now an the count down date
    var distance = countDownDate - now;

    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =  hours + "h "
    + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

    // If the count down is over, write some text 
    if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
    }
}, 1000);
</script>
```

When I use `var now = new Date().getTime();` the countdown works. What is the problem in my code ?

Comment: Please edit your question and try to more clearly state what it is you want to know.

Comment: Have you tried adding `console.log` statements or debugging to see what values aren't matching what you expect?

Comment: With the current code, you are never updating the value of `now` inside the interval block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I'm still not clear on what you want, I believe the following code behaves how you want. The trick is that you need to update `now` at every interval.

```
// given the city's UTC offset
function calcTime(city, offset) { .. unchanged ..}

var xx = calcTime('country1', '+3');
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date(xx).getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {
    // calculate the current time
    var now = new Date(calcTime('country2', '-1')).getTime();

    // Get todays date and time      //1527885631789
    //var now2 = new Date().getTime();  //1527871237519

    // Find the distance between now an the count down date
    var distance = countDownDate - now;

    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
    console.log(hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ");

    // If the count down is over, write some text 
    if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        console.log("EXPIRED");
    }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: perfect many thanks but it sometimes stops for second I mean that if it is 3h 59m 51s may be repeated 3h 59m 51s then go on perfectly this happened from time to time through counting but many thanks for you

Comment: but i need to know where is the problem if i pass the value of now through a variable out side setInterval function why it doesn't work as it needed to be update each time or what ?

Comment: In order for the output of the `setInterval` block to change, you have to change a value, either by calculating it again in the `setInterval` block or updating it elsewhere. An alternative option would be to calculate the number of seconds between the two dates, and then track the number of seconds passed in the `setInterval` block

Comment: but when I refresh the browser it starts counting time from the beginning again

Comment: @MR.alaa what did you expect to happen? That's how client side javascript works

Comment: Many thanks i have solved it using your code and some of modification of what i need